# @Bean Lite Mode doesn't work as documented for POJOs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

It says [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) (emphasis is mine)

> @Bean Lite Mode
>
> @Bean methods may also be declared within classes that are not
>   annotated with @Configuration. For example, bean methods may be
>   declared in a @Component class **or even in a plain old class**. In such
>   cases, a @Bean method will get processed in a so-called 'lite' mode.

However in a pojo without `@Component`, a `@Bean` annotated method is not called during startup and the bean is not available in runtime at all.

What did I miss? May the docs be mistaken?

Comment: The docs are correct... `@Bean` works on any spring managed bean... Just adding it to a class and without making it a spring bean (with either `@Component` or registering it as a bean in XML or using a `@Bean` in a `@Configuration` class) will of course not let Spring detect the `@Bean` method.

Comment: Just to rephrase (for @dalyanz's benefits), @M.Deinum So you are saying that when the docs says `or even in a plain old class`, they implicitly mean that the POJO should first be made spring-managed ? If not with `@Component`, then through XML ? That would be their definition of **plain old class** ?

Comment: It still is a plain old class, it has to be however a spring managed instance for Spring to proces it.

Comment: @M.Deinum I think docs are confusing. It shouldn't imply a pojo is/should be already a managed spring bean. although it's not completely wrong it's really confusing.